# Cassandra-based queues are an anti pattern. What's the solution?

Tags: cassandra, queue, priority-queue

There are numerous suggestions around the web that Cassandra is not a good choice when it comes to persistent scalable queues, including this one from DataStax: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets

Yet very few places mention an alternative. And I think I might need one.

Specifically my scenario is:
There are tasks (let's say 100+ millions of them) that need to be executed at some point in the future. Each task has therefore an associated "runAt" property and tasks need to run at their "runAt" time passes (but small delays are allowed). As tasks complete they need to be removed from the queue. At the same time new tasks are added to the queue at some arbitrary rate (let's say 100s/sec or more) with arbitrary "runAt" values between now and 1 year from now.

A possible implementation would make use of Cassandra's ability to order the columns within a row and use some variant of the read/delete technique (that is read the top of the queue, execute the task(s) and remove them from the queue), which closely resembles the mentioned anti-pattern.

So what would make most sense? Try tuning the suggested workarounds to the point that would make this particular problem work at the expected scale? Or a completely different piece of technology would be more suitable for the job?

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's an anti-pattern is because each delete results in a tombstone (i.e. data doesn't get deleted until compaction). Also, partitions and subsequent rejoins after grace periods without repair is likely to result in deleted data reappearing (e.g. "zombies"). Depending on your data rate, total volumes, cluster size, use case, etc. this may be a tradeoff you're willing to make.

If not, possibly looking at some coordination tool will make more sense. Perhaps Zookeeper can be of use here.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the reasons because of which it's an anti-pattern. It seems though to be a scenario that is rather common, so I was hoping there is an off the shelve implementation.

Comment: It is doable but not easy. Disclaimer, I'm a contributor, but here is a queue based on Cassandra that doesn't use deletes https://github.com/paradoxical-io/cassieq